# How to add a database in the AG Listener SQL server and both created on the primary and secondary SQL Servers?

Tags: sql-server, alwayson, availability

I have builded up A and B as an AG(Availability Groups) with a listener(such as the DNS name is LSN) and connected to the SQL Server with the account LSN.

Now when I creating a database in LSN , the database only created in the A which is Primary AG and nothing happened in B ,the Secondary one.

How can I  make it both created in the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make it both created in the same time?

It seems you have misunderstanding of AG groups.AG groups replicate database level transactions once you add a database to availabilty group

There is no technology which which will replicate create database statement on secondary(further which is read only)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Another question is how can i connect to my AG with DatabaseEngine and create a database there? For example, i got a listener ,a AG, and so on... ...